# Info.plist value as C++ #define

Tags: c++, ios, c-preprocessor

In a C++ iOS project (or any other Mac OS), is there a simple way of making a value available both to the Info.pList settings, and to the code in the form of a preprocessor macro?

Ideally, I would like to have something like this

C++ code:

```
#define MY_VERSION_STRING "1.0"
```

Info.pList

```
CFBundleVersion: ${MY_VERSION_STRING}
```

Or alternatively, is there a way of getting values from the .pList in c++? (Without manually parsing the .pList as xml.)

Comment: Xcode supports Info.plist preprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but you could use the /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy utility in a build script to generate a .h file containing a define with a value extracted from the plist.

To output a value from a plist:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :Path:To:Key' filename.plist
```

Comment: That'll work - I can add a prebuild step to generate the .h file. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered, but I'll add my two cents for posterity.  As Richard mentioned above, Xcode has a couple of options for preprocessing Info.plist files -- the most relevant to the current question are "Preprocess Info.plist" and "Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File".

If your version information is defined in, say `ver.h`, you can include `ver.h` as the prefix file and refer to the version macro directly from Info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

This is all readily doable without involving PlistBuddy at all, entirely using build settings.

you create a user defined build setting for your project/target either in the Xcode UI or if you're familiar with xcconfig files you can define it there in a completely textual  =  form.

1. you create your setting MY_VERSION_STRING with a value of 1.0 as your build setting either in Xcode or in an xcconfig file.
2. in your Info.plist your CFBundleVersion line would have a value of ${MY_VERSION_STRING}
3. you turn on Info.plist preprocessing
4. lastly, make use of GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS build variable. for that build setting you can specify a value of MY_VERSION_STRING=${MY_VERSION_STRING} which will result in your defined and shared build setting definition available in to your c/c++/obj-c code as if you had created it as a #define

Answer (score 0):

Property list can also store arrays or some binary data. How do you represent that? It is very domain-specific. So if you know exactly how do you want each type to be represented in C++, you have to either parse plist file and generate C++ code, be that preprocessor directives, or some code defining arrays, enums etc. There are `PlistBuddy` and `plutil` tools available, but they probably won't be much of a help. The easiest way for me would be to use `perl`, see [Using Perl to Manage Plist Files](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2005/07/29/plist.html) for details.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to do the same thing, this is the script I added to the target before the compilation phase:

```
VERSION=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :CFBundleVersion' Info.plist`

echo "#define VERSION_STRING L\"$VERSION\"" > Version.h
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use #define..., you shoud use in the .plist key, MY_VERSION_STRING, and not ${MY_VERSION_STRING}. This works too with the "Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File". In both cases don't forget to set "Preprocess Info.plist File".